# Angular2 can't enable material design

Tags: angular, angular-material2

As mentioned in the question's title I can't enable material design although I'be followed the official [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).
I did the following steps:
`npm install --save @angular/material`
`npm install --save @angular/animations`
and this is my `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
```

So everything is perfectly installed but right now I'm facing two problems:
The first one is that the compiler can't find the animations module when I try to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`:
[image]
The second problem is that when I import material modules in NgModule like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdIconModule
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get this error in the console, and a bunch of warning messages:
[image]

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You're using `@angular` dependencies with mixed versions (4.2.5, 2.4.0), which are thus not compatible with each other. Use the latest stable version of angular, and use the same version for all the `@angular` dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 4 uses `InjectionToken` instead of `OpaqueToken` which is used by Angular 2 and as you are mixing your `@angular` dependency versions between the two you get a bunch of errors stating that the `InjectionToken` cannot be found.

What I suggest is if this is a new project you can update node/npm by downloading Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and then you update the Angular CLI to the latest version by following those steps:

**Step 1:** run this command to uninstall the old CLI

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
```

**Step 2:** install the CLI globally

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

If this is a big Angular 2 project you can follow [this](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) guide to refactor it to an Angular 4 project.

Comment: you're right sir it was an angular CLI problem, after updating it everything works fine now :).

Comment: @Slimen glad this helped you! really happy to see a tunisian joining the angular community!

Comment: `npm cache clean` is now changed to `npm cache verify` as of `npm 5`

Answer (score 2):

In your package.json, try to replace 
 "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",

with

```
 "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
```

Your  @angular/animations is version ^4.2.5 while the other modules @angular/core, compiler etc is version 2.4.0. Try to update those as well to 4.2.5

Also, try to delete the node_modules in your root folder and run npm install again. Everything else seems fine with the code you provided. Hope this helps

Comment: @SlimenTunis I updated my answer. I didn't notice your animations version is different with your @angular/core and etc.

Comment: but I have installed these dependencies using angular CLI so it will install the last version of each dependency right ?

Comment: If you are using ^ in your package, it will update to minor updates. Take a look at this https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning. Again to be sure, delete your node_modules and run npm install again it usually solves my problem

Comment: oh ok this make sense, I will re-install all the dependencies using the same version.

Comment: @SlimenTunis let me know if you still have problems

Comment: You can alternatively use `npm update` to update all dependencies.

Comment: @brijmcq still the same problem :(

Comment: Problem solved , it was an angular CLI version problem, thnx for your time :)